# Combining info from two population coverage levels from a tolerance interval

Tags: population, confidence-interval, tolerance-interval

I have some existing product data from which I've calculated a tolerance interval with a  95% confidence level with at least 95% of population covered. I would like to use this tolerance interval as a specification for testing a new product to help understand both the safety and efficacy of the new product. Falling below the low-end of the tolerance interval could represent efficacy issues, while exceeding the high-end could represent safety issues (with the assumption that existing product is both safe and effective).

I'm proposing to test new product, and calculate two tolerance intervals (both with 95% confidence level) from the resultant data: One with a 95% of population covered, and one with 99% of population covered.

I would like to then compare the new product bottom value from the 95% population coverage interval to the existing product tolerance interval bottom value as an efficacy measure. I would then like to compare the new product top value from the 99% population coverage to the existing product tolerance interval top value as a safety measure.

My thinking is that this will give me a reasonable indication that new product is both safe and effective while putting additional emphasis on staying away from potential safety issues.

Is this a sound rationale and/or is there a better way to show that?

Thanks,

Ep

Comment: Your terminology is strange. Are you perhaps describing *tolerance intervals*?  Any why should decisions of safety and efficacy relate to comparing new intervals with old ones? Shouldn't they instead be based on meeting actual performance thresholds?

Comment: Thanks Whuber, clarified (hopfully) the post above. 

The problem is that there is no performance threshold (part of what I'm trying to establish with this testing). However, existing device (there are actually a few with which I'm making comparisons) is a representation of the performance threshold. These have been used in many instances with varying levels of success. As such the existing device performance can give a feel for what is both safe and effective.